# Issue with converting strings to postixct class

Tags: r, posixct, readr

My csv file has datetime data in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` When I read the file using `readr::read_csv()`, the datetime fields are loaded into the data frame as character data. When I try to convert these columns using

```
as.POSIXct(data_frame["col name"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I get an error saying do not know how to convert to class POSIXct

[image]

If all the data in the csv file is for times >= 12:00:00 (on 24 hour clock) `read_csv()` will load the data and the datetime fields are dttm objects. If I have records in the csv file with a time less than 12:00:00 `read_csv()` will load the data but the datetime fields are loaded as characters. Subsequently I cannot convert them to datetime in the dataframe  (RStudio 2022.07.2 build 576).

Comment: Try `[[` instead of `[` i.e. `as.POSIXct(test_df[["started_at"]], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` as `[` returns a data.frame/tibble with single column whereas `[[` returns a vector, `as.POSIXct` expects a vector

Comment: You can use `data_frame["col name"] <- strptime(data_frame["col name"],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format. Images of your screen are not useful.

Comment: using [["started_at"]] works! thanks